Show that $x^n-nx+n-1 \geq 0$
the problem
Show that $x^n-nx+n-1 \geq 0$
I thought of taking the L-H-S to this form $x^n-nx+n-1=(x-1)(x^{n-1}+...+x+1-n)$. I dont know what to do forward...I took the cases if x=1, x<1 and x>1 and I've been able to do both x=1 and x<1.
How should I demonstrate the inequality for x>1

Is $n$ a natural number? What about $x$?

@SineoftheTime x is a positive number, while n is a natural nonzero number

Hint: if $x>1$, then $x^k>1$ for all $k\geq0$

@Lorago Oooo...so all the sum of powers would be greater than n and all of the second term of the product would be greater than 0 which makes the inequality, am I right?

Yep exactly, you got it!

It looks like it is true for all $x>-1$

You're pretty close. Notice that you can factor out an $(x-1)$ term from the other factor, namely $ x^n - nx + n -1 = (x-1)^2 [ x^{n-2} + 2x^{n-3} + \ldots + + (n-2)x + ( n-1)  ] $.  So on $ x \geq 0$, this expression is non negative with equality iff $x = 1$.

Applying the AM-GM  inequality: $$x^n + n-1 = x^n +\underbrace{1+1+...+1}_{n-1} \ge n\sqrt[n]{x^n\cdot \underbrace{1\cdot ...\cdot 1}_{n \text{ times}}} =nx$$

second underbrace text should be $n-1$ too, but this still valid of course.

Very original approach (for me!). My own answer takes a completely different path.

I think interesting to note that the two means (AM and GM) are equal in a single case : when $x=1$ (see the geometrical meaning in my solution)

$f_n(x)=x^n-nx+n-1$

$f_1(x)=x-x+1-1=0\ge 0\quad\forall x$

$n\ge 2$ then $f'(x)=n(x^{n-1}-1)$


Has two roots $\pm 1$ for $n$ odd and one root $1$ for $n$ even, in any case $x=1$ is the local minimum (due to sign of $f'$).
Since $f(1)=1-n+n-1=0$ then $f(x)\ge 0$ for all $x$ when $n$ even, and at least on $[-1,+\infty)$ for $n$ odd.
Note:
for $x\ge 1$ you have a shortcut using binomial formula, i.e. $x=1+u$ with $u\ge 0$ and $f(x)=(1+u)^n-1-nu\ge 0$

The inequality, written under the form :
$$\underbrace{x^n}_{f(x)} \geq nx+(1-n)$$
has an immediate interpretation (see fig. below for the case $n=4$) in terms of convexity : indeed, function $f$ is convex on $[0,\infty)$ and $y=nx+(1-n)$ is the equation of its tangent at point $(1,1)$, therefore with a graphical representation below the graphical representation of $f$ .
Some detail : the equation of the tangent to the curve of $f$ in point $(x_0,f(x_0)$ is :
$$y=f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$$
Taking $x_0=1$, we get indeed :
$$y=1+n(x-1)$$


I have added a figure. Any comment ?

One more brave anonymous downvoter ! I am more and more disapointed by the bad spirit existing among some people on StackExchange. Was this downvoter able to produce such an answer ? Or the completely different answer by @NN2 ?

Just give you an upvote. I got also a downvote yesterday. It seems to me that this person downvoted all the answers (perhaps because we answered a closed-question?)

One more anonymous downvoter today (December 22, 2024) Thanks for Chrismas spirit...
